# 301 redirect - Dynamic urls - Keep query strings

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've done a lot of reading here on other places but I'm still struggling with this new htaccess redirect I'm trying to implement.  I've tried various versions of the rewrite but can't get it to work.  Also, still confused on whether I should use QSA or not.

I want my old pages which feature dynamic urls to redirect to the new directory/page I have setup.  The thing is, I don'w want to write an entry for all of the states and countries I have.  I want to keep the exiting query string.

I'm trying to go from:

```
http://example.com/olddir/detailsbyst.php?country=____&state=__&sd=____ 
http://example.com/NEWDIR/detailsbyst.php?country=____&state=__&sd=____
```

The last version I tried was this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^country=([A-Z­a-z­0-9­-]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^state=([A-Z­a-z­0-9­-]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sd=([A-Z­a-z­0-9­-]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^olddir/detailsbyst\.php$ http://example.com/newdir/detailsbyst.php [NC,QSA,L,R=301]
```

On a related note, some of the old dynamic urls have &desc instead of &sd at the end of the query string, so for those urls I would want to convert the &desc to $sd

Thanks - Nick

Comment: This should do the trick: http://chilipepperdesign.com/2009/02/01/htaccess-query-string-301s/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just redirect `/olddir/` addresses to `/NEWDIR/`, you need to use a single RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^olddir(.*)$ /NEWDIR$1 [NC, L,R=301]
```